# Get file_id or file_url of a channel message of telegram API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-api, mtproto

I am getting messages from a telegram channel via [messages.getHistory](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory). The result is [messages.channelMessages](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/messages.channelMessages) which contains a list(Vector) of [message](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/message). Each message can have a [messageMedia](https://core.telegram.org/type/MessageMedia) attached to it which mainly are [messageMediaDocument](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/messageMediaDocument). The document also has a unique document id that is referring to a file such as a video or audio. I am wondering if there is any way to get the file id or file URL of that document on the telegram server. If that is not possible, how can I access that document (which can be video, audio and etc.) somehow?

Comment: Whats your question? Getting the file is the same for channels.

Comment: The question is how to get the file via the document. Does it clarify?

Answer (score 0):

when get channel messages you can retrive file info that can

request TL upload.GetFile and receive file bytes

you can check this [documention](https://gram.js.org/tl/upload/GetFile) for nodejs

another way is check [telegram web z version](https://github.com/Ajaxy/telegram-tt/blob/master/src/lib/gramjs/client/downloadFile.ts) that how download bytes from file server